PHP / Wordpress creating a shortcode as a string
I'm trying to write a shortcode, but it has quotes within quotes within quotes because it has a shortcode in it. This link is breaking and not rendering the href correctly. Here:
<?php
function worksheet($atts){
    $default = array(
        'year' => 'Year-1',
        'title' => 'Writing Numbers',
        'level' => 'Easy',
    );
    $attributes = shortcode_atts($default, $atts);
    
    return "<a href='[s2File download='access-s2member-ccap-free/" . $attributes['year'] . "/" . $attributes['title'] . ".pdf' download_key='true' /]&s2member_file_inline=yes'>" . $attributes['title'] . " (" . $attributes['level'] . ")</a>";
    }
add_shortcode('worksheet', 'worksheet');
  
?>

I've read the other solutions about escaping th quotation marks but it still doesn't work with the following code:
<?php
function worksheet($atts){
    $default = array(
        'year' => 'Year-1',
        'title' => 'Writing Numbers',
        'level' => 'Easy',
    );
    $attributes = shortcode_atts($default, $atts);
    
    return "<a href=\"[s2File download='access-s2member-ccap-free/" . $attributes['year'] . "/" . $attributes['title'] . ".pdf' download_key='true' /]&s2member_file_inline=yes\">" . $attributes['title'] . " (" . $attributes['level'] . ")</a>";
    }
add_shortcode('worksheet', 'worksheet');
  
?>

I'm expecting the same as if I just write the link as follows:
<a href="[s2File download='access-s2member-ccap-free/Year-1/Counting with 10 pence (A).pdf' download_key='true' /]&s2member_file_inline=yes">TEST LINK</a>

I've also tried to use " . chr(39) . ", replacing the quotes. DOesn't work. I have read all the other solutions.

Please note that "doesn't work" doesn't mean anything. You should include what the rendered output is in your question, along with why it doesn't match what you're expecting.

Your code looks mostly correct, but there’s a small issue in how the link is generated with the [s2File] shortcode within your worksheet function. WordPress doesn’t automatically parse shortcodes embedded in href attributes, so using do_shortcode is necessary to ensure that the [s2File] shortcode is processed properly. Here's an updated version of your code that should work as expected:
function worksheet($atts) {
   $default = array(
       'year' => 'Year-1',
       'title' => 'Writing Numbers',
       'level' => 'Easy',
  );
  $attributes = shortcode_atts($default, $atts);

  $s2file_shortcode = "[s2File download='access-s2member-ccap-free/".$attributes['year']."/".$attributes['title'].".pdf' download_key='true' /]&s2member_file_inline=yes";
  $link = do_shortcode($s2file_shortcode);

  return "<a href=\"".$link."\">".$attributes['title']." (".$attributes['level'].")</a>"; } 
}

add_shortcode('worksheet', 'worksheet');

This update uses do_shortcode to process the [s2File] shortcode, ensuring the proper URL is generated and placed within the href attribute.

If you are going to quote strings with double quotes, why bother with concatenation syntax.  IMO, this is harder to read than sprintf() (which uses placeholders and avoids interpolation, concatenation, and escaping noise).

You're trying to render nested shortcodes. The way you're doing it has less to do with quotes, and more to do with how to handle a shortcode within another shortcode. You'll need to render out the inner shortcode using do_shortcode before returning the output of your own wrapper.
I tend to also prefer the use of sprintf to help with quoting and concatenation:
function worksheet($atts){
    $default = array(
        'year' => 'Year-1',
        'title' => 'Writing Numbers',
        'level' => 'Easy',
    );
    $attributes = shortcode_atts($default, $atts);

    // This renders your inner shortcode first, and returns the resulting string
    $downloadLink = do_shortcode(sprintf('[s2File download="access-s2member-ccap-free/%d/%s/.pdf" download_key="true" /]', $attributes['year'], $attributes['title']));
    
    // Then we wrap the result with our extra content
    return sprintf('<a href="%s&s2member_file_inline=yes">%s (%s)</a>', $downloadLink, $attributes['title'], $attributes['level']);
}
add_shortcode('worksheet', 'worksheet');

